# How to View/Create tables in dynamoDB in docker machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I have a docker machine which I start by

> `docker-machine start default`

I built the dynamoDB image just by

> `docker-compose up`

I get the following information displayed after the dynamoDB image is built and the **process just hangs on the terminal**.

```
Starting <something>_dynamodb_1 ...
Starting <something>_dynamodb_1 ... done
Attaching to <something>_dynamodb_1
dynamodb_1  | Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
dynamodb_1  | Port: 8000
dynamodb_1  | InMemory: false
dynamodb_1  | DbPath:   null
dynamodb_1  | SharedDb: true
dynamodb_1  | shouldDelayTransientStatuses: false
dynamodb_1  | CorsParams:   *
dynamodb_1  |
```

**Now, after this I am not really sure about how to view and create the tables from here on**. I tried executing `docker run <DynamoDB image> -p 8000:8000` in the different shell instance but I get

> ```
> usage: java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
>             [-port <port-no.>] [-inMemory] [-delayTransientStatuses]
>             [-dbPath <path>][-sharedDb] [-cors <allow-list>]
> ```

I am uploading the image as well just so that my question makes sense to the viewers.[image]

**docker-compose.yml**

> ```
> dynamodb:
>      image: tray/dynamodb-local
>      ports:
>        - "8088:8000"
>      command: "-sharedDb"
> ```

Comment: What does your docker-compose file look like

Comment: @Pandelis I have updated the question with the contents of docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Just passing in ["-sharedDb"] will not work. Use the list of commands I have below

```
dynamodb:
     image: tray/dynamodb-local
     ports:
       - "8088:8000"
     command: ["-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-inMemory", "-sharedDb"]
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem must be the docker image you are using "tray/dynamodb-local"

try changing it with the [official amazon image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local)

I've also published an image [awspilotcom/dynamodb-ui](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local) which includes a gui as well

many more on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=dynamodb-local&type=image)